# Groovy mock Java class with parameters

Tags: java, groovy, mocking

I'm trying to use groovy's MockFor and proxyDelegateInstance to mock a java class with constructor parameters, but I can't seem to get it right. My Java class looks like:

```
class MyJavaClass {
   private MyObject myObj
   public MyJavaClass(MyObject myObj) {
      this.myObj = myObj;
   }
}

class MyGroovyTest {
    @Test
    void testMyJavaClass() {
        def mock = new MockFor(MyJavaClass)
        MyJavaClass mjc = new MyJavaClass()
        def mockProxy = mock.proxyDelegateInstance([mjc] as Object[])
        // if I pass mockProxy to anything, I get an error that a matching 
        // constructor could not be found. I've tried variations on the args 
        // to proxyDelegateInstance (such as using mjc as a single arg rather than 
        // an array of one element)
    }

}
```

Can I actually do this in groovy? And if so, how can I do it?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the class being mocked was a class and not an interface. In order to use the proxyDelegateInstance method, the an interface type needs to be used (or a groovy class). The proxy class is not actually of the MyJavaClass type but is a proxy and groovy's duck typing can handle that while Java cannot.

Comment: What did you end up using instead?

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell you why your code above is not working, but there are several ways in Groovy to mock Java classes without using `MockFor`. For example, if you want to intercept all calls to the object, you can implement `invokeMethod` on the classes' metaClass, e.g.

```
class SomeJavaClass {
  // methods not shown
}

def instance = new SomeJavaClass()

instance.metaClass.invokeMethod = {String name, args ->
  // this will be called for all methods invoked on instance
}
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to provide an object that supports the method signatures of `SomeJavaClass`, you could use either a `Map` or an `Expando` with properties where:

- property names match method names
- proprerty values are closures that accept the same parameters as methods

If you can provide a bit more information about how the mock object is used, perhaps I can provide some more specific suggestions.

Comment: Don, the problem is if I have another class, let's call it Actor, that takes a MyJavaClass as a parameter and I call actor.doSomething(mockProxy) I get an error about not having the appropriate constructor to create MyJavaClass.

Comment: If Actor is not actually instantiating MyJavaClass, then could you just instantiate MyJavaClass normally, and use `invokeMethod` to override the method implementations?

Comment: At the end of the test, I need to verify MyJavaClass, which is why I've created it as a mock.

Comment: I think the issue is that proxyDelegateInstance doesn't actually return an instanceof the class, rather it returns a class of type class_delegateProxy. This will work in groovy because of the dynamic typing but passing this to a Java class won't work (if this is the problem) since Java is checking the type.

Comment: I meant because of Groovy's duck-typing (not dynamic typing, though groovy is dynamically typed of course) above

Comment: Have you tried using the `proxyInstance` method rather than `proxyDelegateInstance`?

Comment: Yes. I confirmed that the issue is in fact because my class is a class and the proxyXXX methods return something that is not actually of that class type (for classes only though, works for interfaces)